# Android notifications open into Popup "like on iphone"

Tags: android, dialog, popup, notifications

I occasionally get requests to implement or modify notifications to display expanded messages like the dialog popups on iOS.

Of course this doesn't work as planned by the time I am looking at it, or when dealing with the designer or product person, and the response is "well how do other android apps handle it"

The real answer is that android apps don't do this, or they might emulate it, but either way it doesn't go along with the design patterns.

So what would be a good equivalent user experience for a notification that expands into a popup on Android? Not everyone can use big notifications, and notifications can open a background app which can load a dialog if opened that way, but is that the best?

Anyway, I expect that there is a real answer here, instead of a discussion, thanks for any insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use an activity with the theme of a dialog to show as message that would be similar to what iOS does and many apps do it, I dont necessarily think it looks good but that is my opinion.

check [SMSPopup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.everythingandroid.smspopup) for an example